# If cannot read property 'value' of null is true don't execute the following code?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to scrape some content using Puppeteer, when trying to avoid elements that don't match the media I'm seeking to extract, a common `cannot read property 'textContent' of null` error will occur when I try to find an element that doesn't contain any `textContent`.

I'm scraping many dynamic pages, so I can't know for sure the exact iterations to avoid, so instead I just want to avoid executing the function whenever `cannot read property 'value' of null` is returned. I'd like to create a conditional statement that will check if the function will return a null value or specifically this error so I can avoid executing it.

I've tried these two methods with no success, I don't quite understand why though.

```
if (typeof document.querySelectorAll("[id=info]")[i].querySelector("[id=text-container]").textContent !== 'undefined') {
  items.push(document.querySelectorAll("[id=info]")[i].querySelector("[id=text-container]").textContent);
}
```

```
if (document.querySelectorAll("[id=info]")[i].querySelector("[id=text-container]").textContent !== null) {
  items.push(document.querySelectorAll("[id=info]")[i].querySelector("[id=text-container]").textContent);
}
```

Comment: You're not getting the value anywhere in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: `typeof anyElement.textContent` is always a string ... and you need to be sure the element you are looking for is there.

Comment: Why do I need know the element exists to avoid scraping it? I'm not quite following you. Would the problem be solved if I unstring the function at the end?

Comment: It's not `textContent` that's null; it's `document.querySelectorAll("[id=info]")[i].querySelector("[id=text-container]")` that's null; test that.

Comment: Oh that's true, good point.

Comment: That worked. Feel free to post that as a response haha. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read carefully ther error browser reported.

cannot read property 'textContent' of null means not that textContent is null, but the result from querySelector is null. So, you should check the container first. for example:

```
var container=document.querySelector('#yourID');
if (container!==null){
  //read any properties you may need here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check for the element's existence instead. You can use the optional chaining operator to simplify this; it will short circuit and return undefined if we try to access a field or method of null or undefined. This will thus work even if intermediate elements are not found.

```
if(document.querySelectorAll("[id=info]")?.[i]?.querySelector("[id=text-container]") != null)
```